# Rails mysql lost connection

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

My Website **sometimes** cause 500 error (any path)
But after refresh again, 500 error disappear and right page is opened.

Info

```
Rails 4.1.4
MySQL 5.6.25
mysql2 gem 0.3.17
Rails webserver : nginx & unicorn on Ubuntu 12.10
db server : centOS 6.6
```

500 error message

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (Mysql2::Error: Lost connection to MySQL server during query: BEGIN)
```

database.yml

```
production:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  pool: 20
  username: xxxx
  password: xxxx
  host: xxxx
  database: xxxx
  wait_timeout: 300 
  reconnect: true
```

centos 6.6 [mysqld] setting (/etc/my.cnf)

```
bind-address=0.0.0.0
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
init_connect="SET collation_connection = utf8_general_ci"
init_connect="SET names utf8"
character-set-server = utf8
collation-server = utf8_general_ci
skip-name-resolve
wait_timeout=300
interactive_timeout=300
```

Maybe I think there is a problem to mysqld setting because this error start to appear after mysql server has been moved.

I had mysql account before, not linux server. So I didn't need to set mysql config. just using mysql hosting. But now, I have centOS 6.6 server using for mysql, so I install mysqld and use it.

and then the error above has appeared.

How to solve this ?

#### Added

1. There is no effect that changing host to private ip and domain.
2. After adding mysqld setting below

   ```
   general_log=ON
   log_warnings=2
   ```

   log file has no logs about lost connection.

Comment: You are connecting to mysql through your internal private ip or public ip ?
Try using your internal private ip.

Comment: @NitinSatishSalunke I have already tried using domain and private ip. But the problem still appear.

Answer (score 0):

Could this be your `wait_timeout` being set to 300?
I'm not sure how long your connection is idle before reaching back to the DB, but with a setting of 300, MySQL is terminating any sleeping connection at 5 minutes.

If this isn't the case, please run `SHOW VARIABLES;` 
This will help pin point the problem.